# Downloading a non text file from different changeset for viewing [Mercurial]

Tags: mercurial, diff, tortoisehg, dvcs, application-settings

I am in an old changeset at rev 99 and I want to view a non text file say PDF in new changeset at rev 101.

```
Graph  Rev   Branch   Description
o      101+  dev      *Working Directory*
|
o      101   dev      execution time optimization for z
|
o      100   dev      Fixing y
|
0       99   dev      Test x updated
```

Normally if the file is a code file or text its easy to view the difference using any diff tool. I am more interested in **downloading the file to my temp folder for viewing in the file's specific reader software without have to update to new changeset at rev 101**

I tried view at revision but it opens it in some default text editor. From the settings the visual editor dropdown menu shows only notepad++ etc.

Is there a way if I could select different visual tool for based on different file extensions.

Answer (score 1):

For your **task** (see content of binary file) you can have two slightly different solutions

- Use your preferred viewer for such file-types as Mercurial's extension-specific diff-tool (if you have TortoiseHG, you can inspect setting and common concept of introducing `docdiff` for *-Office files - read hgrc.d\MergePatterns.rc + hgrc.d\MergeTools.rc)
- Use the above viewer outside Mercurial|TortoseHG: `hg help cat` - with `hg cat FILENAME -r REV > /PATH/FILE` or `hg cat FILENAME -r REV -o FORMAT-OF-FILENAME` you'll have file outside of repo, in ordinary FS, which can be viewed by any usual tool

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to open a file in the editor/viewer which is associated with it's file extension, then the answer is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

For instance, in TortoiseHG you would:

1. Click back to revision 99 in the history.
2. In the file list, highlight the one you want
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
4. Tortoise will open your PDF using your registered PDF viewer.

You can also find this option in the context menu (right click) called `Open Local`.